# Get data from database using month

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
try
{
    conn5.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = conn5;
    string query = "select * from OrderDataListTable WHERE MONTH(`DATETIME`) = dateString";
    command.CommandText = query;
    reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

What is the right syntax to compare my input month to the database?

```
String dateString = Convert.ToString(textBox2.Text);
DateTime month = Convert.ToDateTime(dateString + "01, 1990").Month;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use something like this with properly formatted string expressions for the dates of the interval:

```
DateTime monthDate = DateTime.Parse(textBox2.Text);
string startDate = new DateTime(monthDate.Year, monthDate.Month, 1).ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd");
string endDate = new DateTime(monthDate.Year, monthDate.Month + 1, 1).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd");
```

and then:

```
string query = "select * from OrderDataListTable where [DATETIME] between #" + startDate + "# and #" + endDate + "#";
```